# How to Process Data outside of Twisted thread

Tags: python, twisted, twisted.internet

I am trying to write a UDP listener that performs an API call in response, but based on the data contained within the received UDP datagram.  It appears callMultipleInThreads runs both functions in a single thread.  Upon receiving a UDP datagram, I was hoping functionOne would end as functionTwo starts in a new thread (to do the API call)  This does not appear to be the case.

```
import time
from twisted.internet import reactor, threads

def functionOne(x):
    print x

def functionTwo(x):
    time.sleep(10)
    print x

commands = [(functionOne, ["First Function"], {})]
commands.append((functionTwo, ["Second Function"], {}))
reactor.listenUDP(9999, threads.callMultipleInThread(commands))
reactor.run()
```

I am new to writing threading code.  How could better allow a second function not block functionOne from closing?  Would forking the API call in funtionTwo be a better method?

Answer (score 1):

As [documentation explains](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.threads.html#callMultipleInThread), **threads.callMultipleInThread** will run your functions on one thread, so they can still block each other. If I understood your goal, you should defer functionTwo to it's own new thread instead of sharing the same one as functionOne. There is a quick section on [how to integrate blocking calls with Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/gendefer.html#integrating-blocking-code-with-twisted) and this is using deferToThread on the blocking call.

The last missing thing I noticed was a Protocol implementation.
So, I will show a quick snippet to demonstrate how to run functionTwo on a new thread while listening for UDP:

```
import time                                                                                                                                                                                                  
from twisted.internet import reactor, threads                                                                                                                                                                
from twisted.internet.protocol import DatagramProtocol                                                                                                                                                       


class DoNotBlockMeProtocol(DatagramProtocol):                                                                                                                                                                
    def datagramReceived(self, data, (host, port)):                                                                                                                                                          
        reactor.callLater(0, functionOne, "First Function")                                                                                                                                                  
        threads.deferToThread(functionTwo, "Second Function")                                                                                                                                                
        print "received %r from %s:%d" % (data, host, port)                                                                                                                                                          self.transport.write(data, (host, port))                                                                                                                                                             


def functionOne(x):                                                                                                                                                                                          
    print x                                                                                                                                                                                                  


def functionTwo(x):                                                                                                                                                                                          
    time.sleep(10)                                                                                                                                                                                           
    print x                                                                                                                                                                                                  

reactor.listenUDP(9999, DoNotBlockMeProtocol())                                                                                                                                                              
reactor.run()
```

In order to see it working, run this on a linux shell:

```
$ echo -n “foo” | nc -4u -w1 localhost 9999
```

You can also learn more about using UDP on this guide: https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/udp.html

Comment: This is not accurate.  By "the same thread", the documentation for `callMultipleInThread` means that it will run all of the functions on the same *non-reactor* thread.

Comment: Thank you for the heads up, @Glyph. I fixed the answer as I have misunderstood the documentation.